# Unsorted didgit in Insertion Sort Algorithm

Tags: java, insertion-sort

```
// this describes the insertion sort algorithm
public class InsertionSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //array of unsorted integers

        int [] array = { 10, 4, 1, 11, 5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 9};

        int n = array.length;

        for ( int j = 1; j<n; j++) {
            //assign a value to the second element in the array
            int key = array[j];

            //assign a value to the 1st element in the list
            int i = j-1;

            //loop executes as long as i>0 and that the element befor the key is greater than the key itself
            while( i>0 && array[i]>key) {

                //move the bigger element 1 block forward
                array[i+1] = array[i];

                // keep moving until the element is in the right position
                i =i-1;

            }
            array[i+1] = key;//assign the key to the appropritae location
        }

         for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
                System.out.print(array[i] + " ");

            System.out.println();
    }

}
```

this is the ouput, As you can see, everything is sorted besides 10, which is still out of place in the array

`10 0 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 11`

Comment: Have you tried debugging this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has a problem:

```
while( i>0 && array[i]>key) {
```

The first iteration, j equals 1 and so i equals 0. And your loop doesn't run, because 0 is not *greater* than zero. But it should run, so the condition needs to change to "greater than *or equals* zero":

```
while( i>=0 && array[i]>key) {
```

That will fix your sort.